# Iteraction of js and PHP file with variables in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm doing a contact form in wordpress, this is a template page, in this page there is also a google map, this map get coordinates from php variables that I can set in the admin panel of wordpress.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/contact-form/map.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var lat=<?php echo($GLOBALS['desklab_theme_settings']['latcord_text']);?>;
                var lng=<?php echo($GLOBALS['desklab_theme_settings']['lngcord_text']);?>;
                generateMap(lat,lng);
            </script>
```

I' ve done so, as advised in another question that I wrote 
The problem is that I must get variables in this php file, so I must to the same with email

```
   <?php
/*
Template Name: ContactForm
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var emailto=<?php echo($GLOBALS['desklab_theme_settings']['email_text']);?>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/contact-form/contactform.js"></script>
```

The problem is that I can' t do the same of map, becuase the js of contact form start at click of contact form's button

```
<input class="btn" type="button" id="button-contact" value="Send" />
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//click of form bottom
$("#bottone-contact").click(function(){
```

After that I go in another PHP file that send email (js)

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "wp-content/themes/DeskLab/contact-form/mail.php",
```

PHP mail.php

```
<?php

session_start();

    $nome       =   $_POST['nome'];
    $email      =   $_POST['email'];
```

How can I do and how can I add the variable `emailto` in the php? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean exactly, but if I understand you correctly, something like this could work. Inside of your form, put a hidden field with your email from server:

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo($GLOBALS['desklab_theme_settings']['email_text']);?>" />
<input class="btn" type="button" id="button-contact" value="Send" />
```